# React form: loop through event.target to create an object

Tags: reactjs, loops, fetch, react-hook-form

I have a rather long form to submit and would like to **create an object** containing the name of the input as a key and the value of the input as the value. I tried looping through the `event.target` and `event.target.elements` as shown below:

```
handleModify(event) {
    let tempPlayer = {}
    Object.entries(event.target.elements).forEach(([name, input]) => {
        tempPlayer[name] = input;
    });
}
```

But I got the TypeError about looping cyclic object value. It is probably not the right way to loop those values, as I saw by logging on the console event.target and event.target.elements actually contain html form elements. I don't know how else to get the form data. My form looks like that:

```
<form onSubmit={e=> props.onSubmit(e)}>
  <label htmlFor="name">
    Name:
    <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Estelle Nze Minko" />
  </label>
  <label htmlFor="poste">
    Poste:
    <input type="text" name="poste" placeholder="Back" />
  </label>
  <label htmlFor="number">
    Number:
    <input type="number" min="0" max="100" step="1" name="number" placeholder="27" />
  </label>
  <label htmlFor="height">
    Height (m):
    <input type="number" min="1.00" max="2.34" step="0.01" name="height" placeholder="1.78" />
  </label>
  <label htmlFor="selects">
    Number of selects:
    <input type="number" min="0" max="300" step="1" name="selects" placeholder="88" />
  </label>
  <button type="submit">Add</button>
</form>
```

I was using this method because it is the way I did it on the server side by fetching the form data and looping the `req.body` entries. However now that I have changed the ejs templates to React I can't send the form data. That is why I am trying to loop through the values directly in the React handle method. I was unable to send the form data with fetch to my **node + express** server. The `req.body` always ended up being empty. I think it is because I am using **body-parser** and I was sending a `new FormData()` (which isn't supported?) as such:

```
handleModify(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    fetch(`/players/modify/${this.props.match.params.id}/confirm`, {
        method: "POST",
        headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
        mode: "cors",
        body: JSON.stringify(new FormData(event.target))
    });
}
```

However, if I create the object first and then send it with fetch, it works. So, does anyone know how to loop through the form elements or how to solve the fetch problem? Thank you :))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not how you should do it in ReactJS. Here's a good tutorial for handling forms: https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html

Basically you need to set a value to each input and handling their respective onChange callback:

e.g.

```
    <input type="text" name="name" value={this.state.name} onChange={onNameChange} placeholder="Estelle Nze Minko" />
```

Then in your component you have a method `onNameChange` which saves the new value to a state for example:

```
onNameChange(event) {
  const name = event.target.value;
  this.setState(s => {...s, name});
}
```

Finally when submitting the form you need to use the values inside this.state

```
handleSubmit(e) {
  e.preventDefault(); // prevent page reload
  const {name} = this.state;
  const data = JSON.stringify({name});
  fetch(`/players/modify/${this.props.match.params.id}/confirm`, {
    method: "POST",
    headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
    mode: "cors",
    body: data
  });
}
```

This is all just an example, I recommend you read the link I gave you first.

LE: Using an uncontrolled component:

https://codesandbox.io/s/dark-framework-k2zkj here you have an example I created for an uncontrolled component.

basically you can do this in your onSubmit function:

```
  onSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    const tempPlayer = new FormData(event.target);
    for (let [key, value] of tempPlayer.entries()) {
      console.log(key, value);
    }
  };
```

Comment: Ok, thank you ! I just changed my components to be controlled. So now to get the object in handleSubmit your `const {name} = this.state` only works for one input right? I'd have to create that data looping through all the states?

Comment: I edited my post and added an uncontrolled version as well (in case you prefer that one)

Comment: yes, using a controlled component you would have to save each input to state and get the data to send from there

Comment: I created the following loop to get all the states in the data object: `Object.entries(this.state).forEach(([name, value]) => {
            data[name] = value;
        });`
However now the numbers are strings, do you know a way to change that (do I have to put a condition on the type of the input and use the Number() wrapper?)

Comment: Sorry this might be out of context for this question, so don't worry about it!

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason you don't use controlled components? You could keep the input values in the state, and when submitting the form, you just use the values from the state.

[React Docs on Forms](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html)

Answer (score 0):

The error seems to come from storing the `input` itself as value, you might have ended up performing an operation on it somewhere. Instead you can store the name and value of input with:

```
tempPlayer[input.name] = input.value;
```

Demo:

```js
const root = document.getElementById("root");

const { render } = ReactDOM;

function App() {
  const handleSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    let tempPlayer = {}
    Object.entries(event.target.elements).forEach(([name, input]) => {
        if(input.type != 'submit') {
          tempPlayer[input.name] = input.value;
        }
    });
    console.log(tempPlayer)
  }
  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      <label htmlFor="name">
        Name:
        <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Estelle Nze Minko" />
      </label>
      <label htmlFor="poste">
        Poste:
        <input type="text" name="poste" placeholder="Back" />
      </label>
      <label htmlFor="number">
        Number:
        <input
          type="number"
          min="0"
          max="100"
          step="1"
          name="number"
          placeholder="27"
        />
      </label>
      <label htmlFor="height">
        Height (m):
        <input
          type="number"
          min="1.00"
          max="2.34"
          step="0.01"
          name="height"
          placeholder="1.78"
        />
      </label>
      <label htmlFor="selects">
        Number of selects:
        <input
          type="number"
          min="0"
          max="300"
          step="1"
          name="selects"
          placeholder="88"
        />
      </label>
      <button type="submit">Add</button>
    </form>
  );
}

render(<App />, root);
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div id="root" />
```

PS: Uncontrolled forms are known to have performance improvements and reduced rerenders as shown in [React hook form](https://react-hook-form.com/). You don't *have* to use a controlled component.

[You may not need Controlled Components - swyx Blog](https://www.swyx.io/writing/no-controlled-forms/)

Comment: Absolutely, thank you. I also found another solution by calling the element's attribute name in a for loop (`event.target.elements[i].getAttribute("name")`) but your solution is better. :)

Comment: Is the name in `[name, input]` obsolete now then? @Agney

Comment: Although this is correct (not needing a controlled form) I still wouldn't get the formData from event.target.elements - it just feels unnatural to loop over the DOM in React.

Comment: @tudor.gergely Feels unnatural is not a valid reason because React itself felt unnatural coming from long time in other frameworks. I linked to react hook form earlier, but here is the usage from [swyx blog](https://www.swyx.io/writing/no-controlled-forms/)

Comment: @Maëlle I'm using the input for `input.value`, so you have to destructure `name to something. But you could also use `Object.values` for a similar result

Comment: @Agney I totally understand. I just think you could've used new FormData(event.taget) instead of looping over the elements but you are welcome to disagree with me (I'm actually happy to debate this and both of us learn something)

Comment: @tudor.gergely If I had to set to check for validity for form fields, I would have to get all form fields by looping over them, I don't see how `FormData` is any better